# Salesforce HttpRequest blob results in Internal Server Error

Tags: apex, httprequest, upload, file-storage

I am currently uploading files to a third-party storage space through its API.
This is the API through Java which was uploaded:

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setHeader("Token", token);
            post.setHeader("UploadPath",
                    Base64.encodeBase64String(uploadPath.getBytes());
            post.setHeader("FileName", Base64.encodeBase64String(fileName.getBytes()));
            post.setHeader("FileSize", Long.toString(fileSize));
            post.setHeader("FileModifiedtime", Long.toString(lastModified));
            post.setHeader("FileEOF", "0");
            post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(fileEntry))));
```

I tried doing this in Apex as:

```
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Token', token);
req.setHeader('UploadPath', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(uploadPath)));
req.setHeader('FileName', EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(fileName)));
req.setHeader('FileSize', String.valueOf(fileSize));
req.setHeader('FileModifiedtime', String.valueOf(lastModified.getTime()/1000));
req.setHeader('FileEOF', '0');
req.setEndpoint(url);
req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
req.setTimeout(60000);
```

The server returns 400 if the request body is empty or the header fields are missing. I have also tried `req.setBody(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(bodyBlob))`. Both the options in Apex yield 500 from the server side. Have checked [this](http://blog.enree.co/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html#finalCode_multipart) and it seems that the requirement is different, sending multi-part form data. However, the server does not accept this type and checks through the body content and the header values. How do I proceed about this?

P.S.: This kind of upload feature is for Document/Attachment body fields.

SOLUTION:
Use the header and chunk it to a byte format as mentioned in 
http://blog.enree.co/2013/01/salesforce-apex-post-mutipartform-data.html#finalCode_multipart
Have to change the server code with base64encoded string. Worked like a charm!

Comment: Have you made your remote webservice web site in your remote site settings list?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to connect to the remote site. The only thing that I'm not able to perform is to upload a file from Salesforce to my remote site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(fileEntry)))); // Binary
```

is different from

```
req.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob); // Blob
```

both are different data types. So, it is expected that code won't work.

Even if you send the blob converting to `Base64` it would not work becasue expected body type is different.

One of the solutions can be is change third party server to read base64 into body and then convert to binary in background. Salesforce support Blob and Base64 only. Binary type is not supported.